# Django/Gunicorn/Nginx: wrong JS files seems to be served

Tags: javascript, python, django, ajax, static

My project works locally

I have deployed my project with [django](/questions/tagged/django)/[gunicorn](/questions/tagged/gunicorn)/[supervisor](/questions/tagged/supervisor) in a remote server

I have a select button (id = id_patient) with a list of options. When the user selects an option, information related to this option are displayed using an ajax request. But on a remote server, information is not displayed.

When I look with my web browser debug tool (see image), it looks like it is not the good js files that are served

But in my static folder on the server, it is the good js files...

```js
// affichage des informations sur le patient sélectionné pour la ré-allocation
$("#id_patient").on("click", function (event) {

    var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $("#form_reallocation").data("patient-url"),
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken,
                'patient': $(this).val(),
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function (data) {
                $("#information_patient").html(data);
            }

        });
    } else {
        $("#information_patient").children().remove();
    }

});
```

[image]

To collect the new static files, I have `run python manage.py collectstatic` and files are collected but I have a warning message that indicate possible duplicate in static files :

> Found another file with the destination path 'randomization/js/script.js'. It will be ignored since only the first encountered file is collected. If this is not what you want, make sure every static file has a unique path.

How can I fix this issue?

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    'crispy_forms',
    'widget_tweaks',
    'bootstrap4',

    'registration.apps.RegistrationConfig',
    'monitor.apps.MonitorConfig',
    'randomization.apps.RandomizationConfig',
    'parameters.apps.ParametersConfig',
    'unblind.apps.UnblindConfig',
    'pharmacy.apps.PharmacyConfig',
    'export.apps.ExportConfig',
    'randomization_pk.apps.RandomizationPkConfig',

    'django_extensions',
    'debug_toolbar',

    'partial_date',
    'safedelete',
    'simple_history',

]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'randomization/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'unblind/static'),
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'pharmacy/static'),
)
STATIC_ROOT = '/home/test/intensetbm_static'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running in production mode, with DEBUG=False, you must configure a webserver to serve static files.

An alternative is use [whitenoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) to serve the static files as a middleware, that wont process the Django pipeline to serve statics.

Try to remove STATICFILES_DIRS, by default Django look for all "static" folders inside INSTALLED_APPS, and use relative path to STATIC_ROOT.

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
```

After that, run :

> python manage.py collectstatic

again.

Comment: my project is deployed in preprod with DEBUG=True and I do run python manage.py collecstatic to serve my static files. And in fact static are served as boostrap css is served...

Comment: Do you have GitHub repository? This way I could help you.

Comment: Try remove STATICFILES_DIRS from settings. Django already looks for static folder inside app.

Comment: I have removed STATICFILES_DIRS and run collectstatic (I do not have warning message anymore) and restarted my server but still not working

Comment: Use relative path on STATIC_ROOT. Read the post, I'm hope to help you.